# Array index can be binary

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I have scenario where need to point the array index in binary.
`A = B[111];`  111 will be in binary which has decimal value 7.

Instead of 7, can I write 111?

Can you please show me the correct way?

I tried to point `A = B[111]` in Verilog, but it is not working the way I expect.

Answer (score 0):

To specify an integer in binary format, you must use the `'b` prefix.  `'b111` is the same as decimal `7`.

```
A = B['b111]
```

You can also specify the size of the integer (the bit width) as 3, for example:

```
A = B[3'b111]
```

`B[111]` does not work as you expected because `111` is in decimal format (one hundred and eleven).  When an integer does not have a prefix, it is interpreted as decimal.

The prefix is known as the base.  There are 4 bases: decimal, binary, hexadecimal and octal.

Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017 section 5.7.1 *Integer literal constants*.